# How do I make it so that this blockquote has a double quotation mark before and after the text?

Tags: css

Struggling on this a bit. Just needed some help adding the double quotation. I need it to double quote just the paragraph in the block quote.

```
q
blockquote {
  background-color: rgb(131, 121, 36);
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;    
  font-family: Comic Sans MS, Times New Roman, cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content: '"';
}
```

Try this. It will create pseudo element.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eh4m6pmz/

Comment: it worked but it changed the color of my block quote and everything.

Comment: Style it as long as you want. I just answered what I need to answer. Right?

Comment: One more, I copied the style from your given css. So, i just used your design. Look at the fiddle and your code. All the same.

Comment: Partially,  I need it to quote just the paragraph in the blockquote. I tried to mess wit  the code a bit and all but it still changed the color and such of my text

Comment: Ok that worked, but how do i get it to put the quotes in the beginning and end of the paragraph inside of the block quote?

Comment: So you need blockquote p:before, blockquote p:after {}